# TV Mount fire block hidden

Tags: drywall, television, mount

[image: TV on wall]
I want to hide this cable behind the wall. I think I’ll use fiberglass or fish cable to send the cable diagonally behind the wall. But I’m worried there may be fire blocks along the diagonal path (behind the post-it note in the attached image). I know how to deal with fire locks but only when they are visible and not if there’s one along this diagonal. Any tips on what I should do here if there is one?

Comment: The wire for that outlet may be coming down from the attic, so you could put an outlet higher up the wall.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run this existing cable through the wall. Normal power cords are not certified for in-wall use.

You **can** install an outlet behind the set, of course. Getting wires through most hidden fire blocks can be done without seeing them if you use one of the drill bits attached to a long flex shaft intended for this purpose, inserted through the opening you'll be installing a new-work box into. (They often can also be used as snakes to pull the wire back through.) Diagonal would be more difficult. Obviously, be careful not to disturb existing wires or pipe -- pull breakers first. You'd want access to either top or bottom of the wall (attic or basement) to run the new wire from, and a circuit and junction box to connect the far end of the wire into.

If you're thinking of taking power from the existing outlet, that's not impossible, but running the wire between that box and the new box is going to be messy. Easiest solution I can think of involved opening at least some of the plaster... in which case, if you really have diagonal blocking, I'd suggest opening the whole vertical rectangle, running the wires and the new box with full access, then patching the plaster. (Useful trick: A few pieces of wood bridging the opening, held in place with screws through retained plaster on both sides, can then be screwed to through the new piece to hold it in place; join up the edges and paint.)

Or, as an alternative to all the above ... It's much easier, and not much uglier, to get surface-mounted cable routing channels and paint them to match your wall. Running the power cord through one of those *does* meet code, since the plaster acts as a firebreak between it and the structure. I took this approach when routing speaker wire; yes, I could have run it inside the walls (low-voltage, and the cable was plenum rated besides), but that would have been a lot more hassle than I wanted to do just now.

Note that simply putting a piece of furniture -- a small table or bookshelf or whatever -- under that display will hide most of the channel. Or most of the cable, for that matter, which may make the whole question moot.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the cable inside the wall is coming from the attic. The easiest and tidiest is to run another cable down and out an outlet behind the TV.

Call an electrician, they have extendable drill bits and can drill down a dwang if its present. They know how to pull cables.

If that fails, ask them to put a white surface mount capping to extend the socket to behind the TV.